# Socket communication between JavaScript and Lazarus Pascal

Tags: javascript, json, sockets, pascal, lazarus

I have a front-end server written in JavaScript and a backend-server written in Lazarus Pascal. Both need to send messages to each other. The data to be transferred are coded in JSON. I think Sockets could do the job. Does anybody has experience in such a scenario or could give me a hint how to achieve this. Would be very much appreciated!

Comment: unit socket has examples in the documentation, I suggest to start there.

Comment: Right. But I haven't found theproper one yet. I'm looking for a server to server communication. Could you help me with a link?

Comment: I generally use Indy, not the sockets unit.

Comment: I'm not fixed on sockets. Just look for a communication between a pascal server and a Javascript program. On the first sight sockets seem to be a viable way. But maybe AJAX works as well?? In general I wonder why there isn't an easier way of doing this such as  a  "netread" and "netwrite" with parameters IPadr, content, errorcode??